Animated Opacity not animating in Flutter
I have a flutter app  wherein I have a stack implementation of containers.
Container at index = 0 (from height * .1 to all the way down) has a button at the bottom which clicked animates another container (index = 1) from bottom upto (height * .2) of Scaffold. This container too has a button at the bottom which if clicked animates another container (index = 2) from bottom all the way to height * .3
My aim is when Container 2 (index = 1) animates on the screen, the bottom most container (index = 0) which still has (height * .1) part of it visible on the screen, I want this part to animate into another container. So basically user selects something on Bottommost container and when container with index = 1 appears, its (container with index = 0) visible part will display the information that the user selected.
problem is the animated opacity widget is not working properly.
This is a tabCubit i am using.
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:cred/business/cubit/tab_state.dart';
import 'package:cred/data/models/selected/selected.dart';

class TabCubit extends Cubit<TabState> {
  TabCubit()
      : super(const TabState(
          activeTab: 0,
          opened: [true, false, false],
          selectedData1: [],
          selectedData2: [],
          selectedData3: [],
          opacity: 0.0, // Initial opacity
        ));

  void switchTab(int tab) {
    final opened = List<bool>.from(state.opened);
    for (int i = 0; i < opened.length; i++) {
      opened[i] = i == tab;
    }
    // Set opacity based on the opened state
    final newOpacity = opened[0] ? 0.5 : 1.0;
    print("New opacity $newOpacity");
    emit(state.copyWith(activeTab: tab, opened: opened, opacity: newOpacity));
  }

  void updateSelectedData1(List<Selected> newData) {
    emit(state.copyWith(selectedData1: newData));
  }

  void updateSelectedData2(List<Selected> newData) {
    emit(state.copyWith(selectedData2: newData));
  }

  void updateSelectedData3(List<Selected> newData) {
    emit(state.copyWith(selectedData3: newData));
  }
}


@freezed
class TabState with _$TabState {
  const factory TabState({
    required int activeTab,
    required List<bool> opened,
    required List<Selected> selectedData1,
    required List<Selected> selectedData2,
    required List<Selected> selectedData3,
    required double opacity,
  }) = _TabState;
}



The ui screen code looks way uglier but I'll just show the essentials:
return Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              context.read<TabCubit>().switchTab(0);
              context.read<TabCubit>().updateSelectedData1([
                Selected(
                    title: emiBloc.emidata?.items?[0].closedState?.body?.key1
                            .toString() ??
                        "",
                    sub: currentValue.toString())
              ]);
            },
            child: state.opened[0]
                ? Container(
                    height: screenHeight * (1 - initialHeight),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.card1,
                      border: const Border(
                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      //Some lengthy code here
                      )
                ) :  
                   AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: state.opacity,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenHeight * (1 - initialHeight),
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20, left: 20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: AppColors.card1,
                        border: const Border(
                            top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                     //Some lengthy column code   
                     )
                 ))
);


The container after the colon just appears. My aim is it should animate alongside the container which is being animated on the screen.
Both widgets have same container decors meaning they look same, difference will be that it will appear as if the information user has selected animates there.
